# Style PHP Variable within HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I've been trying to export a PHP value into an H1. I so far have been unable to do so. I have got as far as using `print $_POST['value']` However I am not able to give this text a style.

My current Code looks like

```
$file_handle = fopen("message.txt", "w");
$file_contents = $_POST['value'];

fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents);
fclose($file_handle);
?>


<div class="output">
    <h1 class="outputTxt">
        <?php echo $_POST['value']; 
        ?>
    </h1>
</div>


<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="value">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I've tried putting the `print $_POST['value']` inside a DIV but I cannot change anything in the css.

I've also tried using `echo $_POST['Value']` however that has had the same result.

I am unable to change the Style of the outputted code. I can get the file "message.txt" to print under the 'value' variable. But I am unable to change the style of this in any way

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Err, I see no `<H1>`? I do see a `<div>` ? How are you expecting the data to be styled, as I also dont see any CSS of any find

Comment: I do not see any form there. So POST will always be empty, if not called from AJAX for example. Show more code. Btw use echo instead of print.

Comment: Are you saying that you are **not allowed to change the CSS** or that this code does not change the CSS?

Comment: I am unable to change the Style of the outputted code. I can get the file "message.txt" to print under the 'value' variable. But I am unable to change the style of this in any way

Comment: Or `echo '<h1 style="color:red;font-size:100px">'. $_POST['value'] .'</h1>';`

Comment: That works. But I'm still unable to get the CSS for the Class to change the style of the output text. Thanks for the help though

Comment: RiggsFolly Thank You! This works.

Comment: Did you include the `.css` file into your HTML `<head>`

Comment: Ha, wow I'm really off today! Thanks for the help. Just included it